# Rails 4: Simple search form with wrong redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have some trouble with simple search form. When I pass information in the form on page:

> /search

and press submit button it collects data and searches but instead of reloading current page it's passing params to index:

> /**claims**?utf8=✓&claim_id=49&phone_number=%2B34(44)444444

But I want to show the result of search on current page (without any AJAX).
If I manually pass those params and change link it's working greate!

> /**search**?utf8=✓&claim_id=49&phone_number=%2B34(44)444444

My *routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :administrators
  resources :claims

  root :to => "sessions#landing"

  ...

  get    'search' => 'claims#search'

  post   'claims/new' => 'claims#new'
  post   'claims' => 'claims#create'
end
```

My search function in controller:

```
  def search
    @claim = Claim.search(params[:claim_id], params[:phone_number])
  end
```

***How can I modify my routes to do that?***

Answer (score 0):

So, couple of things are happening here.   You need to to do 2 things

1. Make sure your controller action can handle multiple types of requests
2. Make sure you have 2 routes, 1 for posting (since you aren't using ajax) and 1 for getting

controller action

```
if request.post?o    
  @claim = Claim.search(params[:claim_id], params[:phone_number])
else
  Claim.all (or whatever you want to display when the page is fresh before a search has been done)
end
```

And your routes are a little messy so lets fix that when we add the post.

```
resources :claims do
  collection do
    get 'search'
    post 'search'
  end
end
```